# Yii relation failing with indexes > 5

Tags: php, debugging, yii

I have a very simple relation defined as follows (`aId` and `bId` are the primary keys for each table).

```
class A extends CActiveRecord
{
    // @var int32 $aId
}

class B extends CActiveRecord
{
    // @var int32 $bId
    // @var int32 $aId

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'a'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'A', 'aId'),
        );
    }
}
```

As long as `bId <= 5`, I can access A through `$bModel->a` without any problems.  What's strange is for `bId > 5`, `$bModel->a` is null.  I've checked `$bModel->aId` for `bId > 5` and the foreign key is correct.  I can even access A with `$aModel = A::model()->findByPk($bModel->aId);`.  I can also manually edit my `bId`s in the database table, which produces the same result.

I have no idea what's causing the relation to fail for primary key's greater than five.  Any suggestions for troubleshooting? I'm at a loss.

**EDITED**

It turns out I wasn't using the relation properly. I should have used BELONGS_TO.

```
class B extends CActiveRecord
{
    // @var int32 $bId
    // @var int32 $aId

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'a'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'A', 'aId'),
        );
    }
}
```

HAS_ONE was causing B to use `bId` to index A.  Since I had five instances of A in my database that worked for `bID < 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable query logging in your application config to see what exactly is happening.
Do you get any results when manually running those queries?

```
'components' => array(

    'db' => array(
        (..)
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
    ),

    'log' => array(
        'class' => 'CLogRouter',
        'routes' => array(
            // Show log messages on web pages
            array(
                'class' => 'CWebLogRoute',
                'categories' => 'system.db.CDbCommand', //queries
                'levels' => 'error, warning, trace, info',
                //'showInFireBug' => true,
            ),
```

(I'd post this as a comment rather than an answer, but it seems I can't)

Comment: That did it. Being able to debug the SQL statement allowed me to see that the wrong index was being used for the reference.  Turns out I needed a BELONGS_TO.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use this -> [Yii Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/malyshev/yii-debug-toolbar) (it is created by my friend here in Ukraine).

Can you provide mysql structure + some example data. Thanks.

Comment: This looks interesting.  marcovtwout's suggestion helped me resolve the issue, so I haven't tried it yet.